# Restrict Control Panel items GPO on Server 2003 - AD is 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, group-policy

I'm having trouble applying a GPO to restrict Control Panel Items on Server 2003. My DC is 2008 R2 and the policy I'm using is: User configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Show only specified Control Panel Items

The thing is, all my Server 2008 and 2012 apply the policy with no problems. I only show the Administrative Tools icon on the Control Panel. But on the 2003 servers the users can't see anything, not even the Control Panel icon.

I read on MSDN that I shouldn't  use the canonical name, but the module name: @%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-22982

I tried them both but none of them work on 2003.

Any ideas? Actually I need to allow access only to the Services console, not all the admin tools but I haven't found the way to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

Step 1: Locate 2008 R2 installation media.

Step 2: Mount installation media on the 2003 Server.

Step 3: Upgrade the 2003 server to 2008 R2.

Step 4: Profit

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

2003 hasn't been supported for years. You should absolutely expect for little things like this not to work, and they never will. It'll never get fixed. Why are you futzing about with Control Panel items, when the only thing that should matter to you at this point is how to get rid of Server 2003 as if it were chlamydia?

Comment: Hahaaha we got rid of every 2003 server in the company but these. When you work on a large organization some things arent just as simple as that. I can't get rid of these 2003's sadly. But thanks for your reply, I agree with you.